# Summary for multiple page

Tags: extjs4, summary

I have a problem with the result of my summary :

I have mutliple page of result and I want the sum of the ENTIRE column  but in my case it give the sum for the columns of each page...

Since my english is very poor , I suppose you didn't understand anything at all lol . So I'm going to  give you an example:

I have this:

***page 1***

total : 2

***page 2***

total : 5

But I want the total of the ENTIRE column in each page like this:

***page 1***

total : **7** (5+2)

***page 2***

total : **7** (5+2)

Here's my code :

```
    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        forceFit: true,
        loadMask: false,
        features: [{
            ftype: 'summary',
            dock: 'bottom'
        }],
        columns: [
            {
                header: ressources.HeaderTypeStockText,
                dataIndex: 'libelleTypeStock',
                summaryRenderer: function(){
                    return '<b> Total <b>';
                },
                flex: 0.1
            },
            {
                header: ressources.HeaderQuantiteText,
                dataIndex: 'quantite',
                summaryType: 'sum',
                flex: 0.1
            },
            {
                header: ressources.HeaderPoidsText,
                dataIndex: 'poids',
                summaryType: 'sum',
                flex: 0.1
            }

        ],
        store: storeGrid,
        // paging bottom bar
        bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: storeGrid,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: ressources.GridDisplayMsg,
            emptyMsg: ressources.GridEmptyMsg
        })
    });
```

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

summaryType could also be a function, the parameter are undocumented but the source code give me this:

```
summaryType: function(store, [records, field]) {
    store.each( **makesum** )
    return sum;
}
```

simply ignore records cause in it are only the records of a page, but with the store you can get them all.

Comment: I tried this but it does'nt work ... It doesn't recognize "each":                                                      `summaryType: function (store,records,field) {var sum,courant = 0;
                        store.each(function (records) {
                            courant = 0;
                            sum = courant + records.get('quantite');
                        });
                        return sum;
                    },`.

Comment: make a console.log(store) and look if it contains a store.

Comment: it contains a store but it doesn't recognize "each" as a function :/

Comment: but it has all other store functions (store.prototype) ?
you could manually iterate over store.data.items instead...

Answer (score 0):

To do this from the client side is finally impossible because the total can only sum what is available, So I had to send this info from the server as another field.